# First bigger javascript / jquery website nearly finished - what to do before going live?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I just finished my first single site application project, most lines of code are in JS / Jquery with a backend (called with Ajax ofc) of Asp.net / C#.Net and a MSSQL Server.

I have around 10000 lines of code in total, 8K of that iin JS / JQuery.

I am going live this week, so what is to do to clean up such a big single site app?

What I have done:

- comment methods / classes
- make hard and complex code more readable
- explain unclear code with comments
- delete up out-commented code (source safe will save it for later then)

Is there something in geenreal I miss here?

Additional to your ideas, I have a idea to do, but I don't know how... In C#/Asp.net my Visual Studio gives me a warning or an error for syntax check, variable checks (e.g. unused variables, double used variables etc.) - is there a tool or a way to do this for my js files?

Recommend every help, thanks :)

Comment: Documentation, maybe?

Comment: have you obfuscated your code? One safety major to protect your code.

Comment: @Maas: No need because the project is developed for a customer who will host it for his firm and will have access to the code itself

Comment: @Anjan: Thanks, forget to mention, was a project where is allready a documentation, but nice idea.

Comment: If caught earlier I would have suggested MVC Razor and Typescript. Typescript will add strong typing to JavaScript/jQuery. MVC adds many features that make testing easier. Bundling, to combine JS files is great for reducing load times and make full use of browser caching. You could still apply a typescript to syntax check your JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of this is specific to javascript or ASP.NET but for web applications in general. Basically the first time you expose your applications to real users, you have:

- silly users, who don't do things the way you want them to.
- naughty users who try to bring your site down or steal/destroy your data
- lots of users, who may be individually good, but collectively overload your site and expose performance issues

So to deal with this you need to:

- Test that everything works. Ideally you have automated end-to-end tests but if not, test manually. Note your tests, so you can automate them for next time.
- Run through your application with erratic users who enter incorrect stuff, change workflow, etc. Does anything break?
- Security test. Can I login as someone else? SQL injection? XSS? etc. If you deal directly with money or credit card numbers, I would get a professional penetration test done.
- Performance and load test. Use a tool like gatling or jmeter, or something equivalent on the .NET side and hit your commonly used server functions with N users at once. N could be 10, 100, 1000000, depending on your requirements.

Once the application is released, monitor your logs carefully and fire fight :)

Comment: Thanks for that, the most of that is done allready or not needed because e.g. authentification is with windows auth, so not possible to login as another user here... But great list!

Answer (score 1):

Here are few things you may check(in case you have'nt already)

1. Minify all your 8000 lines of jquery code and use the minified version in your production site.

   ```
   https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html
   ```
2. Ensure you set the compilation node debug property to false. (Something developers tend to forget)

   ```
    <compilation debug="false"/>
   ```
3. Ensure compression is turned on
4. Remove the unnecessary headers. [You may refer to this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506093425/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120209-1.aspx)
5. Ensure your connection settings are encrypted from config files
6. Perform DB maintenance activities : rebuild indexes, statistics